# Configure Fiddler2 for flash

Tags: flash, httpwebrequest, fiddler

Fiddler2 does not log requests made through flash applications. It is picked up in wireshark, but wireshark does not offer the simple interface and the formatted content.

How can I configure Fiddler2 to log requests made by flash applications?

Comment: You need to add more context. What "flash applications" are you referring to? I've never seen Flash fail to send HTTP requests to Fiddler; are you sure that the requests in question are actually using HTTP and not TCP/IP?